# Changing some values in df column based on another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df with multiple columns and values. Say:

| ID | Name | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Jo | $10 |
| 345 | Bella | $20 |
| 567 | IgnoreMe | $5000 |

I also have a defined list of names to ignore. In this example, it contains one value, but it can have more.

`names_to_ignore = ['ignoreme']`

The goal is to replace all cost values with null when `Name` is in the ignore list.

I tried:

```
    #aligning conventions
    df = df.apply(lambda var: var.lower())
    ignore_set = [x.lower() for x in ignore_set]

    #ignoring
    df.loc[df['Name'] in ignore_set, 'Cost'] = ''
```

But it didn't work. I get:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
names_to_ignore = ['ignoreme','IgnoreMe']
```

Finally:

```
c=df['Name'].isin(names_to_ignore)  #checking if this condition satisfies or not
df.loc[c,'Cost']=float('NaN')
```

**OR**

via `np.where()`:

```
#import numpy as np
df['Cost']=np.where(c,np.nan,c)
```

**OR**

via `mask()`:

```
df['Cost']=df['Cost'].mask(c)
```

**OR**

via `where()`:

```
df['Cost']=df['Cost'].where(~c)
```

Comment: Genius, thanks!  What's the most efficient way among the four?

Comment: @GavrielGoidel first 2 methods...ie...via `.loc` and via `np.where()`.....`np.where()` is the fastest in terms of speed

Answer (score 0):

You can try `np.where()`.

```
 df['cost'] = np.where( (n for n in df['Name'] if n in names_to_ignore), None, df['cost'])
```